# Find the value of $\sqrt{i+\sqrt{\frac12i+\sqrt{\frac13i+\dots}}}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Find the value of $\sqrt{i+\sqrt{\frac12i+\sqrt{\frac13i+\dots}}}$ .

Is it convergent, even ?

Comment: FWIW, Mathematica® has this settling down numerically to about 1.18548 + 0.56919$i$ within 100 terms.  (It gets the same value for 1000 terms.)  I used the recursion $a_{nn} = i/n$, $a_{nk} = i/k +\sqrt{a_{n,k+1}}$ and looked at $\sqrt{a_{n1}}$ for various  $n$.  I don't claim this shows convergence.

Comment: Use Ramanujan's identity, that may work. see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical)

Comment: You also asked about $\sqrt{i+\sqrt{i+\sqrt{i+\dots}}}$.  One can show that the argument of that is decreasing and bounded, hence convergent.  The magnitude is bounded, so there is at least a convergent subsequence.  Then one should be able to compare your current sequence to that one.  Sorry, my analysis is too rusty to fill in the details.  Take this as a suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$\begin{align}r_1&:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R, a\to\sqrt{a} \\
r_{n+1}&:\mathbb N\to\mathbb R, a\to\sqrt{a+r_n(a)}&\forall n\in\mathbb 
N\end{align}$$
$$s_n(a)=r_n(a)/r_{n-1}(a)$$
$$s_1(a) = r_1(a)$$
$$\sqrt{i+\sqrt{\frac12i+\sqrt{\frac13i+\dots}}}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty s_n(i/n)$$
This may make computation a bit easier.